# Configure DNS to forward email to google

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, gmail

I'm trying to reconfigure a bind record on an Ubuntu 9.04 server so that email is redirected out to gmail  My existing records look like this (not the real ip)

```
; MX Records
@   IN  MX  10  mail

; Address Records
@   IN  A   70.88.42.67
www IN  A   70.88.42.67
ftp IN  A   70.88.42.67
mail    IN  A   70.88.42.67
```

Am I correct in thinking that the change that is needed is simply

```
; MX Records
@       IN      MX      10      mail

; Address Records
@   IN  A   70.88.42.67
www IN  A   70.88.42.67
ftp IN  A   70.88.42.67
mail    IN      CNAME   ghs.google.com
```

I'm making the changes to the db file held in /var/cache/bind and subsequently going to restart bind to apply them.  Is this sufficient?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You probably want something like this. (see [link](http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?answer=33915))

```
    IN  MX  1   ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
    IN  MX  5   ALT1.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
    IN  MX  5   ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
    IN  MX  10  ASPMX2.GOOGLEMAIL.COM.
    IN  MX  10  ASPMX3.GOOGLEMAIL.COM.
    IN  MX  10  ASPMX4.GOOGLEMAIL.COM.
    IN  MX  10  ASPMX5.GOOGLEMAIL.COM.
```

Make sure you add that [trailing period](https://serverfault.com/questions/18113/).

Comment: I ALWAYS forget the trailing period on FQDN, and the silly DNS server NEVER does what I want until I go back and put the Period in:-)

Answer (score 6):

From Google: Configuring Your MX Records: Other domain hosts

http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?answer=33915

Answer (score 0):

You cannot reference a CNAME record in your MX record. You will need to obtain the correct MX entry from Google.